# How to code on pinescript: "Open position at the exact time the price reaches the MA" (and not at the closing of the period)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would want to code a strategy where I buy exactly when the price reaches the EMA252. The EMA changes during the day, following the price changes. So I have choosen to buy when the price reach the `ta.ema(close[1], 252)`, to facilitate the process and the backtesting.
The problem is that the order is sent at the closing of the day or at the opening of the next day (if I use the function `process_orders_on_close=false`). I have tried to use a buy limit order but the buy limit order is only effective starting from the day after.

So when the price bounces on the EMA of the previous day, the buy order is sent way too late and way too high: at the closing. How to correct it?

My code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("MA bounce simplified", overlay=true, initial_capital = 100000, default_qty_value=100, pyramiding=0, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, calc_on_every_tick=true, process_orders_on_close=true)

//input
length_ema = input (252, "length_ema")
gp2 = "strategy inputs"
x = input (0.30, "x:", tooltip="The open order is send not right on the MA but X % above the MA", group=gp2)
z = input (5, "z:", tooltip ="Take profit Z period after the opening of the position", group=gp2)
stop_loss_pct = input(title="Stop-Loss %", defval=4.00, group=gp2)
xV = close * (x/100)

//Moving Averages (1 = day -1)
ema = ta.ema(close, length_ema)
ema_1 = ta.ema(close[1], length_ema)
ema_1x = ta.ema(close[1], length_ema) + xV

//Conditions
longcondition = ta.crossunder(low, ema_1x)

// Execute trade if condition is True
if (longcondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
if ta.barssince(longcondition) == z 
    strategy.close_all(comment = "close")
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("stop Loss", stop=strategy.position_avg_price*( (100-stop_loss_pct)/100))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html#backtesting-and-forwardtesting

In backtesting strategy calculates on the close of the bars, and market orders filled on the first tick on the next bar's open. You can override strategy to create an order and execute it on the close of the bars with `process_orders_on_close = true`.

`calc_on_every_tick = true` allows you to do what you want, but only in forwardtesting (i.e on realtime bars).